# Проблема с маршрутом. Ошибка No route matches [POST] "/users/14/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При редактировании юзера выскакивает ошибка

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/14/edit"
```

C чем это связано?
Контроллер

```
 def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

View с формой

```
= form_for :user do |f|
    = f.text_field :type, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Поменять роль"
    = f.submit
```

В `routes.rb`

```
resources :users
```

Я понимаю что мне нужен post-запрос, а выскакивает get, но почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До экшена `update` дело даже не дошло.

`form_for` принимает целый ворох параметров, на самом деле. Но почти все необязательны.

1. ключ, под которым параметры формы будут лежать
2. URL, на который нужно отправить форму (по умолчанию текущая страница)
3. HTTP-метод (`GET`/`POST`/`PUT`, и т. д., по умолчанию `POST`)

- *(и ряд других, но другие не относятся к вопросу)*

---

Многие из них можно передать в форме *"вот тебе объект модели, разбирайся сам"*:

1. Ключом будет название модели в `snake_case` и единственном числе.
2. URL:

   - если `.new?`, на `модели_path` соответствующего ресурса
   - иначе (если `.persisted?`) на `edit_модель_path(объект)` соответствующего ресурса
3. Аналогично выбору выше, `POST` или `PUT` соответственно.

---

Иногда имеет смысл задавать параметры вручную:

```
form_for :ключ, url: адрес, method: http_метод
```

Передав только символ, вы задали **только ключ**.
URL и метод остались по умолчанию для форм вообще (текущая страница и `POST`).

Но обычно всё-таки используют объект модели. Для формы под создание берут `Модель.new`, под редактирование, соответственно, редактируемый объект.

Answer (score 0):

`= form_for :user do |f|` - вывод формы для создания новой сущности.
Чтобы вывести форму для редактирования конкретного пользователя, нужно сначала его получить в контроллере:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

чтобы отрисовать форму для его редактирования, во вьюхе:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  ...
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е. для action `new` нужно использовать символ `:user`, а для редактирования - `@user`. Но как тогда их в partials использовать? Я там обычно использую `@user`.

Comment: Только сейчас заметил: *"вывод формы для создания новой сущности"* -- нет. Хотя это может сработать в случае, когда форма создания расположена на традиционном для `index` месте, т. к. путь получится совпадающим, а форма делает POST по умолчанию.